# boost::mutex / How to test if a mutex is locked

Tags: boost, mutex

I know, I know, the title of my message may seem provocative, since 
boost::mutex purposefuly do not expose lock / unlock (in order to avoid dead locks).

However the boost documentation is quite short on these aspects (to say the least), so I am asking if anyone can help me in the following use case.

Suppose you have a class Foo, which has :
- a destructor that takes some time to complete
- a method that is called by a distinct thread, but should not be called during destruction

```
class Foo
{
 public:

  virtual ~Foo()
  { 
    //Time consuming operations here
  }


  //Method called by a timer belonging to a distinct class 
  void OnTimer()
  {
    //Other time consuming stuff. Should not be called during destruction !
  }  


};
```

I tried (with no success) to implement a version based on boost::mutex

```
//boost::mutex implementation
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
  }

  virtual ~Foo()
  { 
    {
      boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mDisposingMutex);
      //Time consuming operations here
    }
  }


  //Method called by a timer belonging to a distinct class 
  void OnTimer()
  {
    {
      //Imaginary code here: mutex::locked() method is private !!!
      if ( ! mDisposingMutex.locked()) 
        return;
    }    
    //Other time consuming stuff. Should not be called during destruction !
  }  

private:
  boost::mutex mDisposingMutex; 
};
```

Am I totally wrong? Can anyone tell me how this is supposed to be done with boost::mutex?

Thanks !

Comment: Why is your object being destructed while another thread still has a pointer to it?

Comment: Not answering the question directly, can you cancel the registration provoking the `OnTimer()` call as the first step in your destructor? Granted, a call could still come through asynchronously "at the same time", but it's not clear yet why this object undergoing destruction is still a target for these callbacks.

Comment: @Anon : Agreed, this is a code smell. I'm still interested in the answer though.

@Seh : Your comment is based on the same code smell. However, I cannot cancel it directly without breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Another alternate approach to consider: Forget the mutex and define a state model through which you move with atomic transitions, like the Java library's `FutureTask` class. Define an enumerated state model including `ALIVE`, `DESTRUCTING`, and `DESTRUCTED` (maybe). Upon entry to the destructor, atomically change the state to DESTRUCTING (via CAS if you're paranoid), and (maybe) change it to `DESTRUCTED` upon exit from the destructor. In `OnTimer()`, only do the work if the state is ALIVE. If you need to preclude the destructor from starting while `OnTimer()` is running, you need a lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do commit to using `Lockable::lock()` in the destructor body, you could have your `OnTimer()` function use [`Lockable::try_lock()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.lockable.try_lock), and proceed only if that function returns true. That will have `OnTimer()` put the destructor on hold if `OnTimer()` starts first, but it *still* doesn't solve the problem of the destructor running, finishing and releasing the mutex, and then `OnTimer()` starting and successfully grabbing the mutex.

Such a sequence is likely in the realm of undefined behavior, but that curse won't stop it from happening. Using a state flag *in addition to the mutex* -- similar to what I described in my comment above -- could allow you to detect this latter case and stop `OnTimer()` from doing anything beyond reading the flag. At some point, though, this is just putting Band-Aids on top of Band-Aids.

Answer (score 4):

@Seh : I totally agree this is a code smell and I should (and will) correct the root cause.

However, in the hope of helping anyone who would  encounter the same problem as me (i.e fighting with the boost doc),  I tried to implement your suggestion. 
The code below now compiles correctly (though the code smell is now very strong)

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

//boost::mutex implementation
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() :
    mIsDisposing(false)
  {
  }

  virtual ~Foo()
  { 
    {
      boost::try_mutex::scoped_try_lock lock(mDisposingMutex);
      if ( ! lock.locked())
      {
        //Die by horrible death, or wait before trying again...
      }
      else
      {
        mIsDisposing = true;
      }
      //Time consuming operations here
    }

  }


  //Method called by a timer belonging to a distinct class 
  void OnTimer()
  {
    {
      boost::try_mutex::scoped_try_lock lock(mDisposingMutex);
      if ( ! lock.locked() || mIsDisposing )
      {
        return;      
      }
    }    
    //Other time consuming stuff. Should not be called during destruction !
  }  

private:
  boost::try_mutex mDisposingMutex; 
  bool mIsDisposing;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

mutex::try_lock()

Comment: This returns false if you're the one who locked the mutex.